# Fortran: Initialize character string with unknown length in main program

Tags: string, initialization, fortran, character

I have a character string I would like to initialize with intent(out) data from a subroutine call. I kind of looks like that:

```
character(*) :: path
call get_path(path)
```

The compiler tells me:

> Error: Entity with assumed character length at (1) must be a dummy
>   argument or a PARAMETER

The construct works just fine in a subroutine but fails in the main program. Is it possible to initialize the path variable without knowing its length?

EDIT: Stuff I already tried but failed.

```
character(99) :: path_temp
character(:), allocatable :: path
call get_path(path_temp)
allocate(path(len(trim(path_temp))))
```

> Error: Shape specification for allocatable scalar at (1)

I don't get why the compiler thinks path is a scalar.

---

A function that returns a character with assumed length apparently is illegal.

```
character(*) function get_path ()
    get_path         =     '/path/to/folder/'
end function get_path
```

> Error: Character-valued module procedure 'get_path' at (1) must not be assumed length

---

What works but gives me a headache because I find it very bad style is to give path an insane length and trim it every time it's used. I think my compiler is having trouble with allocatable character strings because it isn't quite up to date (mpif90). Not sure if it supports them.

Comment: This possibly isn't quite a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25051108, but please read it and see if it answers your question.

Comment: You have the wrong idea about unknown length.  It does not represent "I don't care how long", so much as "length not specified here".  But the length does have to be specified *somewhere*, as the program must provide the appropriate amount of storage for it.  You could possibly solve your problem by making `get_path()` a function *returning* the path as a `character(len=*)`, instead of trying to accept it as an argument.

Comment: Can you use an allocatable string?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908053/allocatable-character-variables-in-fortran

Comment: Does `path` have an expected maximum length? Depending on the situation, I'll temporarily store a string of unknown length into a long, fixed-length variable, then use `trim()` and `adjustl()` to strip whitespace before storing it in a variable-length `allocatable` character variable.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I played around with what you suggested but couldn't make it work (see added code snippets in original post). I am now using a fixed-length variable which gets trimmed every time it's used. Not too happy with that work around...

Comment: The compiler thinks `path` is a scalar because it is.  It's a scalar character of deferred length, not a character array.  To allocate such a scalar with length `x`, say, do `allocate (character(x) :: path)`, or just do `path=trim(path_temp)` and have the deferred length `path` allocated on intrinsic assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many of the points are covered in other answers linked by comments, such as what "assumed length" requires and how to allocate the *scalar* deferred length character variable.

I'll point out two things, before coming to an particular answer.

Intrinsic assignment to a deferred length allocatable scalar character variable results in (if required) allocation of that variable to the length of the expression.  That is

```
character(99) :: path_temp
character(:), allocatable :: path

call get_path(path_temp)
allocate(character(len(trim(path_temp))) :: path)  ! Note the correct form
path = TRIM(path_temp)  ! Or path(:)=path_temp
```

can be replaced by

```
character(99) :: path_temp
character(:), allocatable :: path

call get_path(path_temp)
path = TRIM(path_temp)
```

The other thing to note is quite pedantic, but using the terminology incorrectly may hinder searching.  *Initialization* in Fortran means something specific which isn't applicable here.

You say that a function with an assumed length character result is apparently illegal, based on the compiler error message

> Error: Character-valued module procedure 'get_path' at (1) must not be assumed length

That isn't entirely true: character function results can (currently - it's an obsolescent feature of modern Fortran) be of assumed length in some circumstances.  They must, though, be external functions.  See that the compiler complains about a module procedure (which then isn't external).

That said, having an assumed length character result doesn't help you.  The length of the result still has to be assumed from something, and that something isn't in the function body, but a declaration that defines the external function in a scope.

Something like

```
implicit none

character(99) get_path    ! The length of the get_path result is assumed from here
character(:), allocatable :: path

path = TRIM(get_path())
...
```

As you seem to have complete control over the subroutine `get_path`, there's the final answer-worthy comment to make.  You could directly have the argument allocatable.

```
subroutine get_path(path)
  character(:), allocatable, intent(out) :: path
  path = '/path/to/folder/'   ! Allocation through intrinsic assignment
  path = TRIM(path)           ! In general, if it's likely to have trailing blanks
end subroutine
```